# How to make global variable in pinescript(Tradingview)

Tags: variables, abstract, pine-script, trend

I am working on creating a trend indicator in tradingview to track which way the trend is going. Specifically, I want a variable that will stay the same over days, but when a certain condition is met it will change. It seems like it should be simple to do, but everytime I try I get thrown into a never ending loop and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Variable "Trend"

```
///Condition
pos = close > open
neg = close < open

pos_cond = pos and pos[1]
neg_cond = neg and neg[1]

///Variables to keep track of trend

Trend = iff(***pos_cond or neg_cond not met***, Trend[1], Trend + real_trend)

trend_change_neg = iff(pos_cond, 1, 0)
trend_change_pos = iff(neg_cond, -1, 0)

real_trend = trend_change_neg + trend_change_pos

Trend = iff(Trend > 2, 2, iff(Trend < -2, -2, Trend))

/////////plots
plotshape(Trend > 0, color = color.green, location = location.top, style = shape.square, title="TrendLong")

plotshape( Trend == 0, color = color.yellow, location = location.top, style = shape.square, title = "TrendNeutral")

plotshape( Trend < 0, color = color.red, location = location.top, style = shape.square, title = "TrendShort")
```

So basically what I want to do is keep a running total for Trend where each time there are 2 consecutive candles against the trend it will switch to neutral, but as the trend continues to move in 1 direction it can build back up to +-2 (This was we are never more than 2 "pullbacks" away from neutral. I've racked my brain over this for days now, but if anyone has any ideas any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use var.
Example:

```
var a = 0
a:=close>open?1:0
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html